# What do we need to deploy our app w/ Crystal Reports to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2008

We're building a web application in VS2010, using the .NET 4.0 FW. Our application includes reports that pull data from our database server.

What runtimes or redistributables do we need to deploy to our web server (Windows Server 2008 Standard)? And where do I find them? Is there anything we need to purchase?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [msdeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy/) tool for your purposes.